# Mule "this transformer needs a valid endpoint" error only in runtime not in studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I get a transformer exception running my project on Mule ESB 3.7.5 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, but not when I run the same project in Anypoint Studio with Mule 3.7.5 on Windows. This exception occurs when I use this transformer:

```
 <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message to MoodleCourse"   metadata:id="d3a95670-da14-4d1c-b4df-9eb559593dfb">
 <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/java
 ---
 {
     academicYear: payload.collegejaar,
     category: payload.organisatieonderdeel,
     fullName: payload.lange_naam_nl,
     idNumber: payload.cursus,
     shortName: payload.cursus,
     summary: payload.doel,
     teachers: payload.docenten map ((docenten , indexOfDocenten) -> {
         userName: docenten.medewerker
     }),
     teachingCycles: payload.aanvangsblok_onderwijsvormen map ((aanvangsblokonderwijsvorman , indexOfAanvangsblokonderwijsvorman) -> {
         name: aanvangsblokonderwijsvorman.aanvangsblok
     })
 } as :object {
     class : "zuyd.MoodleCourse"
 }]]></dw:set-payload>
 </dw:transform-message>
```

and then do an http request for the first time:

```
<http:request config-ref="Moodle_HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="${moodle.webservice.path}" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP get_users_by_field" metadata:id="d0589922-6eeb-4171-b4a8-a4a118a8cd78">
     <http:request-builder>
         <http:query-param paramName="wstoken" value="${moodle.webservice.wstoken}" />
         <http:query-param paramName="wsfunction" value="core_user_get_users_by_field" />
         <http:query-param paramName="field" value="username" />
         <http:query-param paramName="values[0]" value="test" />
         <http:query-param paramName="moodlewsrestformat" value="json" />
     </http:request-builder>
 </http:request>
```

The logger runs every time. On Linux the following exception occurs. The data from the payload is not used by the http-request.

```
2018-06-20 15:45:58,893 [[osiris-moodle-v0.0.17].httpListenerConfig.worker.01] INFO  org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor - test1 testmule
 2018-06-20 15:45:58,920 [[osiris-moodle-v0.0.17].httpListenerConfig.worker.01] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
 ********************************************************************************
 Message               : This transformer needs a valid endpoint (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
 Code                  : MULE_ERROR-64999
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Exception stack is:
 1. This transformer needs a valid endpoint (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
   org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer:203 (null)
 2. This transformer needs a valid endpoint (java.lang.IllegalStateException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
   org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer:79 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Root Exception stack trace:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: This transformer needs a valid endpoint
     at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer.getSession(AbstractJmsTransformer.java:203)
     at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer.transformToMessage(AbstractJmsTransformer.java:65)
     at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage.transformMessage(ObjectToJMSMessage.java:54)
     + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
 ********************************************************************************

 2018-06-20 15:45:58,956 [[osiris-moodle-v0.0.17].httpListenerConfig.worker.01] DEBUG org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger - LISTENER
 HTTP/1.1 500 This transformer needs a valid endpoint (java.lang.IllegalStateException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: MoodleCourse
 Content-Length: 259
 MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
 Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2018 13:45:58 GMT
 Connection: close

 This transformer needs a valid endpoint (java.lang.IllegalStateException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: MoodleCourse
```

Does anybody now what causes this exception and why I don't get it in Anypoint Studio?

Comment: there is a bug open on this: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8251

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea how I can workaround this error?